# Is there a goodness of fit test that I can use to check if my data best fits a normal distribution of a poison distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, poisson-distribution, goodness-of-fit, continuous-data, discrete-data

Using the Easyfit add-in on excel I can calculate the Kolmogorov Smirnov and the Anderson Darling statistics. But is it correct to compare those value?

Comment: Do you have any negative values or noninteger values? If so, your data couldn't be Poisson. What do you want to know this for anyway? No real data are ever perfectly normal or Poisson. They are mathematical idealizations.

Comment: Hey, there are no nonegative values or noninteger values; I'm looking at sales numbers on a weekly level. I got the sales data for 52 weeks and I’m now calculating safety stocks. For references with low sales (10 per year) the Poisson fits very well. But if sales increases (400 per year) it may be better to use a normal distribution. I can calculate the Kolmogorov Smirnov or Anderson Darling statistics for both but can I compare them. If the KS-value for the Poisson distribution is 0,3 and the one for the normal distribution is 0,9, can I conclude the Poisson distribution is the best fit? Thx